# SQL Setting MTD based on Ending Date

Tags: sql, datetime, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008

I'm wanted to make sure I am doing this right. This section of my report has been set to default the current MTD. What I need to do is set the report to the MTD if the user changes the end date [image: select date]

The issue I ran into was using `IF Month(@EndingDate)` to check the date and if it wasn't the current month then use the Ending Date and then go back to the beginning of the month. It worked fine until I went into 2011. So I changed my code to this using `IF Year(@EndingDate)`:

```
Declare @startdate  datetime
Declare @enddate  datetime
--Declare @EndingDate datetime


--set @EndingDate = '11-15-2011'

IF Year(@EndingDate) = DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0, @EndingDate),0)
BEGIN
set @startdate = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1,    getdate()), 0)), 0)--BEGINNING OF CURRENT MONTH
set @enddate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)--THROUGH CURRENT MONTH (TODAY)
END

ELSE
IF Year(@EndingDate) < DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GetDate())+1, 0)-1
BEGIN
set @startdate = dateadd(m,datediff(m,0, @EndingDate),0)--Beginning of Month from @Enddate
set @enddate = @EndingDate 
END
```

So as you can see I've switched it to check to see if the Ending Date year matches this year or not and then get the data based on that.

Is this a logical way to do this? My problem now is that for the current year I'm getting all of the correct data but when I go back to last year I'm missing data from certain plants. I've checked a different report and there should be data for every plant so I wanted to make sure that I had my date comparison set up correctly.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are attempting to do, can you provide more details of what you're trying to do instead of what you've done so far?

Comment: can you explain exactly what you are trying to do?  Maybe post some sample data of the data that is passed in (EndDate) and the result that you want.

Comment: @bluefeet I certainly can. I hesitate doing that because I seem to get trolled when I do that. So I'm gun shy about doing that at first.

Comment: @AaronSmith the more info you give at the beginning the better. then we have a better idea of where you are coming from to help.

Comment: Sorry gang. What I am asking is if this is an acceptable method for checking to see if the `Year` in the `@EndingDate` is this year then do the MTD calc. Otherwise if the `Year` in the `@EndingDate` is not the same as this year (2012) then use the `@EndingDate` as the `@enddate` and then go to the beginning of that month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but I think changing the dates behind the scenes can be deceptive for users and may cause you more headaches down the road.  You should simply get the data for the dates they have selected.  You can easily set the default date to the month start in the RS report using the expression below.  This way the users are seeing what they're expecting instead of a date that is generated behind the scenes.

Month Start Date

```
=Now.AddDays(-Today().Day + 1).Date
```

Comment: this wasn't was I was asking BUT you actually hit on another question. Is there a way to set the `TO:` date to the beginning of the month based on the `Beginning Date` input of the user? For example: if they pick `Beginning Date: 2/12/2012` and an `End Date: 2/21/2012` in SSRS I would like my to date to be `TO: 2/1/2012`